# Installing Aptana Studio

Tags: node.js, aptana3

When installing Aptana Studio I get the message "Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file CRC. I have seen this message in archives but nothing that I found helps. I have removed and re-installed node.js on my machine. This worked for many but not for me.

Appreciate any pointers people can give me.